# Set UTF-8 for Vietnamese Android

Tags: android, string, utf-8, server

I need to send string (vietnamese) from Android devices to server like this:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Constants.URL.UPDATE_CURRENT_STATUS);
    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("location", "Thạch thất Hanoi "));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,
                HTTP.UTF_8));
        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        int respnseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (respnseCode == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            return EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

But when server gets the string, its not like

```
Thạch thất Hanoi
```

its become

```
Tháº¡ch Tháº¥t Hanoi
```

My code in server side:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/UpdateCurrentStatus", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = { "application/json" })
    @ResponseBody
    public MessageDTO updateCurrentStatus(
                @RequestParam Map<String, String> requestParams) throws TNException {
      String location = requestParams.get("location");
      System.out.println(location);
    MessageDTO result = driverBO.updateCurrentStatus(location);
              return result;

}
```

How can I resolve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: the problem is on server side, are you storing this data in some database? what kind of database?

Comment: its become 'Tháº¡ch Tháº¥t Hanoi' when i recieve text from android, its not because of database

Comment: can anyone help me in this case, please?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set you android httpclient `Content-Type` header to **application/json; charset=utf-8** instead of "application/json"?

I think your problem is that the content entity `location` you sent is encoded correctly in UTF-8 but server failed to acknowledge UTF-8. clarify it in Content-Type header.

You can diagnose http content and its header with great http monitoring tool [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler).

**-EDIT BELOW-**

Relace your `UrlEncodedFormEntity` as below. Set header to `application/json; charset=utf-8` as I described earlier. it's good to set it up still.

```
        JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
        jsonParam.put("location", "Thạch thất Hanoi ");
        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonParam.toString(), "UTF-8");
        httppost.setEntity(entity);
```

Comment: when i set content-type header in android , it become _Th%3Fch+th%3Ft_ when i receive in server side

Comment: it's not working , **Tháº¡ch Tháº¥t Hanoi** again, dont you think that i have mistake in my server side ?

Comment: because i test in browser by POSTMAN, it happen too

Comment: I don't have enough java server knowledge. I recommend you to ask about java server encoding again. Clien-side would have no problem if you do as follows.